# How to conditionate a Query to do not accept non existent fields

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a query inside my controller that it is working but it also work when recibe parameters that doesn't exist

I tried to use HTTP status response code but the result is the same it creates an empty array when you manually type a URL

This is the code inside of Controller

```
function getPosts(req, res) {
     var type = req.params.type;
     posts.sequelize.query("SELECT forum.id, forum.forum_type, posts.id, 
     posts.post_topic_author_id, posts.post_topic_title, posts.forum_type_id 
     FROM posts, forum WHERE posts.forum_type_id = forum.id AND forum.forum_type = ?", { replacements: [type], type: posts.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(posts => {
     res.status(200).send({ posts })
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Ocurrio un error' + err })
    });
}
```

This is the code inside my Routes

```
const postsController = require('../controllers').posts;

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.post('/api/post-create', postsController.create);
    app.put('/api/post-update/:id', postsController.update);
    app.get('/api/post-get/:type', postsController.getPosts);
}
```

i need to send the user to something like a 404 page for when he manually tries to enter to a URL that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware to handle error.

for example:

- Install hbs

> npm install hbs

- create a directory views and use this code in app Object:

  ```
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
  ```
- Create a error.hbs file in views directory and add the following code in this file:

  ```
  Message: {{message}} 

  Status: {{error.status}}
  ```

  Stack: {{error.stack}}
- catch 404 and forward to error handler

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  });

I hope it can help you.